# Extracting e-mail addresses from Sharepoint site/database

Tags: sql, database, sharepoint

I would like to extract e-mail addresses from a Sharepoint site/database.
One list item in Sharepoint can contain several addresses inside a textbox, so I need some sort of regular expression or other trick to recognize what is an e-mail address and what is not.

So I'm not sure which approach is the best.
SQL Queries and/or script?

Comment: Not an easy job. I suggest you write a c# code to connect to the SharePoint site and extract the email Ids

Comment: Perhaps I will just copy-paste all the info manually and fix it up in an excel document. But it would be really awesome if there was some easy way to extract all the text, then look through it with like a regular expression to determine whether it's an email addy or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the custom code in C# that will traverse through each and every item of the list. If one item of the list contains more than one email address then there should be email separator character like semicolon or comma. You can break/split the string from that point and then check each token with regular expression to verify if it is a valid email address or not.

I hope this helps!